# Apply Regex to df add values in new column

Tags: python, regex

This is my dataset:

```
BlaBla 128 MB EE
ADTD 6 gb DTS
EEEDC 2GB RS
STA 12MB DFA
BBNB 32 mb YED
```

From this data set I would like to extract the number of MB/GB and the unit MB/GB. Therefore I have created the following Regex:

```
(\d*)\s?(MB|GB)
```

The code that I have created so that the regex will be applied to my df is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d*)\s?(MB|GB)')
invoice_df['mbs'] = invoice_df['Rate Plan'].apply(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group(1))
invoice_df['unit'] = invoice_df['Rate Plan'].apply(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group(2))
```

However when applying the regex to my df it give the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: And what if you make the pattern case-insensitive? `(?i)(\d+)\s*(MB|GB)`? I'd also use `+` with `\d` and `*` with `\s`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still the same error message

Comment: So, some entries just do not contain a match, and you access `group(1)` and `group(2)` without checking if a match occurred.

Comment: Yes that is what I expect as well. I know that there are entries where no match occurs...and I would like to keep them empty.

Comment: Try `apply(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group(1) if pattern.search(x) else "")`

Comment: of course, how can I miss this, thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew!!

Comment: Why do you use a lambda, and why would you execute the search twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of the entries may have no match, the `re.search` fails (returns no match) for them. You need to account for those cases inside the lambda:

```
apply(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group(1) if pattern.search(x) else "")
```

I also advise to use

```
(?i)(\d+)\s*([MGK]B)
```

It will find 1+ digits (`\d+`, Group 1) followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) and will match `KB`, `GB`, `MB` into Group 2 (`([MGK]B)`) in a case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that something has been found before requesting the groups :

```
import re

inputs = ["BlaBla 128 MB EE",
"ADTD 6 gb DTS",
"EEEDC 2GB RS",
"STA 12MB DFA",
"BBNB 32 mb YED",
"Nothing to find here"]

pattern = re.compile("(\d+)\s*([MG]B)", re.IGNORECASE)

for input in inputs:
    match = re.search(pattern, input)
    if match:
        mbs = match.group(1)
        unit = match.group(2)
        print (mbs, unit.upper())
    else:
        print "Nothing found for : %r" % input

# ('128', 'MB')
# ('6', 'GB')
# ('2', 'GB')
# ('12', 'MB')
# ('32', 'MB')
# Nothing found for : 'Nothing to find here'
```

With your code :

```
pattern = re.compile("(\d+)\s*([MG]B)", re.IGNORECASE)
match = re.search(pattern, invoice_df['Rate Plan'])
if match:
    invoice_df['mbs'] = match.group(1)
    invoice_df['unit'] = match.group(2)
```

It's more readable than a lambda IMHO, and it doesn't execute the search twice.